# modifying AST as constructed in gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I would like to add a few branches to the AST as being constructed by the parser of gcc, https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/parser.cc

What is the variable that holds the AST as being constructed by the parser?

There is no field in struct cp_parser that contains anything about the AST.